# Place heat pump unit on concrete walkway or dirt/gravel?

Tags: air-conditioning, heat-pump

The picture shows the location for a new heat pump. And as part of an upcoming hardscaping project, we will pour concrete in all this area to build a walkway:

[image]

We would like the HP to be installed ASAP. However, hardscaping is not happening very soon. My main question is:

- Should I wait until concrete is poured, so my HP has a base as level as it gets?

Related questions:

- Say we install HP first and later pour concrete. Once the HP is connected and functional, is it doable/recommended to temporarily remove it and put back only after concrete has set? Is this sth I can do, or must it require the HVAC contractors?
- (A comment needing confirmation, not a question) The HP will come with a plastic pad. My ground is quite level on its own, though I have no idea if the HVAC contractor is interested/willing to put in gravel for further leveling. If we install HP first and later pour concrete, there will be a dirt gap between the pad and the concrete.
- Anything I should consider, if I put the plastic pad on the concrete walkway, and then the HP on top?

In case it matters, the unit we're installing is a [Mitsubishi MXZ-SM60NAM-U1](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3l2ncyhg2158g8l23ipe8/MXZ-SM60NAM-U1-Specifications.pdf?rlkey=d3ieeywgauwxfu98s0yom2vbg&dl=0). Dimension is 53"H 13"D which seems nontraditional and (I guess) may require anchoring into the wall.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the pump rests on a frame which elevates it 12-18 inches (above common snow amounts?), which in turn rests on a platform, which in turn rests on whatever gravel they had to use to get it roughly level. The manufacturer may have more explicit requirements/instructions.